# Use several `Meteor.call` from an arbitrary sequence

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am essentially trying to take a set of data, perform an action on the server with it, and then update the interface. For a simple example, something like this:

```
Template.load.events({
  'click button[data-action="start"]': function (e, template) {
    $(e.target).attr('disabled', true); // disable button until done.
    let next = Scheduler.getNextFromQueue();
    _.each(next.jobs, function (job) {
      Meteor.call('loadJob', job._id, function () {
        // Perform a few asynchronous operations
        // continue to next iteration on completion
      });
    });
  }
});
```

For a test meteor call (to see if it runs synchronously), I tried using this meteor method.

```
Meteor.methods({
  'loadJob': function (jobId) {
    Meteor.setTimeout(function () {}, 10000);
    return;
  }
});
```

However, this returns immediately to the client on every iteration.

How can I run multiple `Meteor.call`s in synchronous sequence on the client?

Comment: Why do you `setTimeout`? It's meant to run asynchronously. Do you know about `Meteor._waitForMs`?

Answer (score 0):

`Meteor.setTimeout` calls a function in the future based on the provided delay in ms. It returns a handle immediately that can be used to clear the timeout. If you want to delay the `Meteor.method` from returning you can wrap a `setTimeout` in a fiber, or use the built in `Meteor._sleepForMs` which is implemented like below:

```
Meteor._sleepForMs = function (ms) {
  var fiber = Fiber.current;
  setTimeout(function() {
    fiber.run();
  }, ms);
  Fiber.yield();
};
```